# How do I use std::hash::hash?

Tags: hash, rust

I am trying to play with Rust's `std::hash` function:

```
use std::hash::{hash, Hash, SipHasher};

#[test]
fn hash_test() {
    println!("{}", hash::<_, SipHasher>(&"hello"));
}
```

I get this error:

```
error: use of unstable library feature 'hash': module was recently redesigned
```

My Rust version is:

```
rustc 1.0.0-beta (9854143cb 2015-04-02) (built 2015-04-02)
```

Is this syntax no longer valid?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The original question was trying to use a feature that was *unstable* - which means it isn't allowed to be used in a stable release, like 1.0-beta or 1.0. Since them, the function has been removed from the language.

The replacement is to write your own version, which allows you to specify the hash function. Additionally, using `SipHasher` directly is deprecated. If you need a specific hashing algorithm, you should pull it from crates.io. Otherwise, you can use an unspecified hashing algorithm from the standard library:

```
use std::hash::{Hash, Hasher};
use std::collections::hash_map::DefaultHasher;

#[derive(Hash)]
struct Person {
    id: u32,
    name: String,
    phone: u64,
}

fn my_hash<T>(obj: T) -> u64
where
    T: Hash,
{
    let mut hasher = DefaultHasher::new();
    obj.hash(&mut hasher);
    hasher.finish()
}

fn main() {
    let person1 = Person {
        id: 5,
        name: "Janet".to_string(),
        phone: 555_666_7777,
    };
    let person2 = Person {
        id: 5,
        name: "Bob".to_string(),
        phone: 555_666_7777,
    };

    println!("{}", my_hash(person1));
    println!("{}", my_hash(person2));
}
```

Comment: This totally worked. Thanks. Do you know if the core team plans to have std::hash::hash stable for 1.0? I was confused because the docs listed this feature as stable here: http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/hash/index.html

Comment: @DorkRawk Stability is finer-grained than that — the *module* is stable, but [the *function* is not](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/hash/fn.hash.html). Unfortunately, I don't know if the method is slated to be stabilized. It's kind of a special use case - most people don't want to get the hash code directly, anyway. What's your use case?